# Accessing a property of an object in php

Tags: php, object, properties

I am trying to access the property of a certain object, but its now working. This is the full result.

So how can i access the lat property in the location object? For some reason its not working

```
SimpleXMLElement Object
(
    [status] => OK
    [result] => SimpleXMLElement Object
        (
            [type] => postal_code
            [formatted_address] => Workington, Workington, Cumbria CA14 3QP, UK
            [address_component] => Array
                (
                    [0] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                        (
                            [long_name] => CA14 3QP
                            [short_name] => CA14 3QP
                            [type] => postal_code
                        )


                )

            [geometry] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                (
                    [location] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                        (
                            [lat] => 54.6352139
                            [lng] => -3.5516768
                        )

                    [location_type] => APPROXIMATE

                )

        )

)
```

i am trying to get the lat property, but its not working

this is what im using

```
echo $result->result->geometry->location["lat"];
```

Comment: `location` is an object itself (not an array), so `..->location->lat` should do the trick

Comment: lol iv been at this for hours lol, that worked :D

Comment: Sometimes when you work too long on something, you get kind of a tunnel vision and it is good to take a step back, a deep breath, and sometimes let a stranger look over the code - so don't worry ;)

Answer (score 0):

Result should be

```
echo $result->result->geometry->location->lat;
```

Not

```
echo $result->result->geometry->location["lat"];
```